# Change a function to support IO String instead of String

Tags: haskell, io

I get an IO String via:

```
import Data.Char
import Network.HTTP
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

openURL :: String -> IO String
openURL x = getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (getRequest x)

crawlType :: String -> IO String
crawlType pkm = do
  src <- openURL url
  return . fromBody $ parseTags src
  where
    fromBody = unwords . drop 6 . take 7 . words . innerText . dropWhile (~/= "<p>")
    url = "http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/" ++ pkm
```

and I want to parse its data via:

```
getType :: String -> (String, String)
getType pkmType = (dropWhile (== '/') $ fst b, dropWhile (== '/') $ snd b)
                  where b = break (== '/') pkmType
```

But like you see, `getType` doesn't support the IO String yet.

I'm new to IO, so how to make it working?
I also tryed to understand the error when giving the IO String to that function, but it's too complicated for me up to now :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First**, to emphasize: *an `IO String` is not a string*. It's an IO action which, when you bind it somewhere within the `main` action, will *yield* a result of type `String`, but you should not think of it as some sort of “variation on the string type”. Rather, it's *a special instantiation of the `IO a` type*.

For this reason, you almost certainly do *not* want to “change a function to support `IO String` instead of `String`”. **Instead**, you want to apply this string-accepting function, as it is, to an *outcome of the `crawlType` action*. Such an outcome, as I said, has type `String`, so you're fine there. For instance,

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   pkm = "blablabla"
   typeString <- crawlType pkm
   let typeSpec = getType typeString
   print typeSpec -- or whatever you wish to do with it.
```

You can omit the `typeString` variable by writing<sup>†</sup>

```
   typeSpec <- getType <$> crawlType pkm
```

if you prefer; this corresponds to what in a procedural language might look like

```
   var typeSpec = getType(crawlType(pkm));
```

**Alternatively**, you can of course include the parsing right in `crawlType`:

```
crawlType' :: String -> IO (String, String)
crawlType' pkm = do
  src <- openURL url
  return . getType . fromBody $ parseTags src
  where
    fromBody = unwords . drop 6 . take 7 . words . innerText . dropWhile (~/= "<p>")
    url = "http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/" ++ pkm
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>If you're curious what the [`<$>` operator](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%24%3E) does: this is not built-in syntax like `do`/`<-` notation. Instead, it's just an infix version of `fmap`, which you may better know in its list-specialised version `map`. Both list `[]` and `IO` are [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor), which means you can pull them through ordinary functions, changing only the element/outcome values but not the structure of the IO action / list spine.</sub>

Comment: This answer is fantastic. You helped me a lot. Thank you!