# How to use "IO String" as an HTTP response in Happstack?

Tags: haskell, happstack, hdbc

I'm retrieving data from a database using HDBC, then trying to send this data to a web client using Happstack.

```
myFunc :: Integer -> IO String
myFunc = ... fetch from db here ...

handlers :: ServerPart Response
handlers =
    do decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "/tmp/" 0 1000 1000)
       msum [ 
                dir "getData" $ ok $ toResponse $ myFunc $ toInteger 1
            ]

mainFunc = simpleHTTP nullConf handlers
```

When I build the above code I get this error:

> No instance for (ToMessage (IO String)) arising from a use of
>   `toResponse'

**What did I try ?**

1. I tried to convert the `IO String` to `String` (using `liftIO` for example).
2. I tried to find any similar questions here.
3. I tried to find a similar example in the Happstack Crash Course.
4. I googled all related keywords in all different combinations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend to read a monad tutorial. There are many in the web. `IO String` vs `String` is one of the classic "common issues" in Haskell. You are trying to do pretty advanced stuff (Happstack) which involves monads (and possibly monad transformers). Grasping monads will not provide the immediate solution to your specific problems, but will tell you that certain approaches like trying to convert `IO String` to `String` can not work (in a sense, a main design feature of the `IO` monad is precisely to prevent such conversion).

Comment: Cf. [*How can I parse the IO String in Haskell*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11229854/2751851), [*transforming IO String to String*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5948300/2751851), [*Change a function to support IO String instead of String*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35613771/2751851).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to design your `handlers` around the fact that fetching from a database is a [magical action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767895/2108477) that may not give you what you expect. (For example, your database may crash.) This is why its result is served as an `IO`, which is a particular case of a **monad**.

A monad is a jar with a very narrow neck, so narrow even that, once you put something in there, you cannot unput it. *(Unless it happens to also be a `comonad`, but that's a whole another story and not the case with `IO` nor with `ServerPart`.)* So, you would never convert an `IO String` to a `String`. Not that you can't, but your program would become incorrect.

Your case is kind of tricky as you have two monads at play there: `IO` and `ServerPart`. Fortunately, `ServerPart` builds upon `IO`, it is " *larger* " and can, in a sense, *absorb* `IO`: we can put some `IO` into a `ServerPart` and it will be a `ServerPart` still, so we may then give it to `simpleHTTP`. In `happstack`, this conversion may be done via [`require`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.0.1/docs/Happstack-Server-Monads.html#v:require) function, but there is a more general solution as well, involving *monad transformers* and `lift`.

Let's take a look at the **solution with `require`** first. Its type (simplified to our case) is:

```
IO (Maybe a) -> (a -> ServerPart r) -> ServerPart r
```

— So, it takes an `IO` jar with some argument and makes it suitable for a function that lives in the `ServerPart` jar. We just have to adjust types a bit and create one *lambda abstraction*:

```
myFunc :: Integer -> IO (Maybe String)
myFunc _ = return . Just $ "A thing of beauty is a joy forever."

handlers :: ServerPart Response
handlers = require (myFunc 1) $ \x ->
    do decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "/tmp/" 0 1000 1000)
       msum [
                dir "getData" $ ok $ toResponse x
            ]

mainFunc = simpleHTTP nullConf handlers
```

As you see, we have to make 2 modifications:

- Adjust `myFunc` so that it returns `Maybe`, as necessitated by `require`. This is a better design because `myFunc` may now fail in two ways:

  - As a `Maybe`, it may return `Nothing`, which means `404` or the like. This is rather common a situation.
  - As an `IO`, it may error out, which means the database crashed. Now is the time to alert the DevOps team.
- Adjust `handlers` so that `myFunc` is external to them. One may say more specifically: *abstract `myFunc` from `handlers`*. This is why this syntax is called a lambda *abstraction*.

`require` is the way to deal with monads in `happstack` specifically. Generally though, this is just a case of ***transforming* monads** into larger ones, which is done **via [`lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift)**. The type of `lift` (again, simplified), is:

```
IO String -> ServerPart String
```

So, we can just `lift` the `myFunc 1 :: IO String` value to the right monad and then compose with `>>=`, as usual:

```
myFunc :: Integer -> IO String
myFunc _ = return $ "Its loveliness increases,.."

handlers :: ServerPart Response
handlers = lift (myFunc 1) >>= \x ->
    do decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "/tmp/" 0 1000 1000)
       msum [
                dir "getData" $ ok $ toResponse x
            ]

mainFunc = simpleHTTP nullConf handlers
```

As simple as that. I used the same lambda abstraction trick again, but you may as well use *do-notation*:

```
myFunc :: Integer -> IO String
myFunc _ = return $ "...it will never pass into nothingness."

handlers :: ServerPart Response
handlers = do
    x <- lift (myFunc 1)
    decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "/tmp/" 0 1000 1000)
    msum [
            dir "getData" $ ok $ toResponse x
         ]

mainFunc = simpleHTTP nullConf handlers
```

**P.S.** Returning to the story of large and small jars: you can put `IO` into `ServerPart` precisely because `ServerPart` is also *an `IO` monad* — it is an instance of the [`MonadIO` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html). That means that anything you can do in `IO` you can also do in `ServerPart`, and, besides general `lift`, there is a specialized `liftIO` function that you can use everywhere I used `lift`. You are likely to meet many other monads out there that are instances of `MonadIO` as it's a handy way of structuring code in large applications.

In your particular case, I would stick with the `require` way nevertheless because I think it's how the designers of `happstack` meant it to be done. I'm not particularly knowledgeable about `happstack` though, so I may be wrong.

That's it. Happy hacking!

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning `liftIO` (alongside, or even instead, `lift`), tying in with the OP's mention of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer.. I already tried to use `lift` before but I get this error `Variable not in scope:
  lift :: IO String -> ServerPartT IO (ServerPartT IO Response)
Perhaps you meant 'liftM' (imported from Control.Monad)`, and I couldn't find which package or interface I missed.

Comment: @asp You're welcome! The module hierarchy and the package interdependencies in the case of monads and monad transformers are more complicated than they could be, due to historical reasons, but one can usually find what one seeks in [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/).

Comment: @Kindaro I used the `require` function and it works perfectly. Thanks